Facing issues while connecting to QuickBooks online through the application
We are facing some issues with QuickBooks' online connection. Recently, we migrated our code base from Java11 to Java21, spring Boot 2.4.3 to Spring Boot 3.3.3, and QuickBooks 6.0.7 to QuickBooks 6.4.1. While connecting to QuickBooks through our application, it is not redirecting back to our application due to some issue. Earlier versions worked fine, but after the migration, we are getting errors.
Here is the code snippet where I am getting an error
public String getCompanyName(String accessToken, String realmId) throws Exception {
        DataService dataService = serviceFactory.getDataService(accessToken, realmId);
        String query = "select * from companyinfo";
        **QueryResult executeQuery = dataService.executeQuery(query);** // this line we are getting error
        String comapnyDisplayName = "QB Company";
        List<CompanyInfo> entities = null;
        if (executeQuery != null) {
            entities = (List<CompanyInfo>) executeQuery.getEntities();
            if (entities != null && !entities.isEmpty()) {
                comapnyDisplayName = entities.get(0).getCompanyName();
            }
        }
        return comapnyDisplayName;
    }

In this last line I am getting some errors.
Logs:
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.intuit.ipp.data.MonthEnum` from String "January": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [OCTOBER, SEPTEMBER, JUNE, MARCH, MAY, APRIL, JULY, JANUARY, FEBRUARY, DECEMBER, AUGUST, NOVEMBER]
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.intuit.ipp.data.CompanyInfo["FiscalYearStartMonth"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:1958)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleWeirdStringValue(DeserializationContext.java:1245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer._deserializeAltString(EnumDeserializer.java:447)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer._fromString(EnumDeserializer.java:304)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:273)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:310)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4881)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3035)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:3499)
    at com.intuit.ipp.serialization.QueryResponseDeserializer.deserialize(QueryResponseDeserializer.java:134)
    at com.intuit.ipp.serialization.QueryResponseDeserializer.deserialize(QueryResponseDeserializer.java:48)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4881)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3035)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:3499)
    at com.intuit.ipp.serialization.IntuitResponseDeserializer.getQueryResponse(IntuitResponseDeserializer.java:327)
    at com.intuit.ipp.serialization.IntuitResponseDeserializer.deserialize(IntuitResponseDeserializer.java:198)
    at com.intuit.ipp.serialization.IntuitResponseDeserializer.deserialize(IntuitResponseDeserializer.java:54)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3848)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3816)
    at com.intuit.ipp.serialization.JSONSerializer.deserialize(JSONSerializer.java:302)
    ... 95 more

Does anyone know why this error is occurring? Is it related to Java, Spring Boot, or QuickBooks Online?

The error is that your MonthEnum is in PascalCase but the library expects it to be in ALLCAPS.
Cannot deserialize value of type `com.intuit.ipp.data.MonthEnum` from String "January": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [OCTOBER, SEPTEMBER, JUNE, MARCH, MAY, APRIL, JULY, JANUARY, FEBRUARY, DECEMBER, AUGUST, NOVEMBER]

January -> JANUARY

true but it is a problem jackson is dealing with enum not from the author's code

I have the same problem and solved some part of it.
you might need to exclude jackson from the import
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.quickbooks-online</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-platform-api</artifactId>
    <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
    <version>${quickbook.api.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

You can try to make the query more specific:
i.e.
String query = "select CompanyName from companyinfo";

It worked for me.
However, to solve the problem properly I had to downgrade to spring 2
